# Postgres - two selects to two json arrays

Tags: postgresql

How can i make two SELECT's into two json arrays from the same table?

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║  users       ║ 
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

How to combine this two selects in one query?

First select example

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(arr1) as arr1
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE id>1
) arr1
```

Second select example

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(arr2) as arr2
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE id<2
) arr2
```

Exprected:

```
[arr1: [{id:1}, {id:2}], arr2: [{id:1}, {id:2}]]
```

Comment: The expected output is not valid JSON array syntax. What do you really want, an object?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, each of 2 selects should have different where

Comment: So, just `SELECT json_agg(*) AS arr1, json_agg(*) AS arr2 FROM users`?

Comment: That's not what your expected output shows

Comment: @Bergi i want to make two separate selects in one go and place each result in a separate row

Comment: @ZiiMakc Separate row? Did you mean separate column?

Comment: @Bergi doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [conditional aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) for that:

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(u) filter (where id > 1) as arr1,
       JSON_AGG(u) filter (where id < 2) as arr2
FROM users u
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ef8e653515418a033f6dd0ed104fdf48))</sup>